# C++ GetLine() Problem, Command Line Program

Tags: c++, iostream, getline, cin

I am writing this program for my programming class and it has a bunch of stupid constraints like I must use nested if else statements and I have to use the cin.getLine() to get a players name. It is supposed to grab the name of each player and calculate their batting average.

**This is not the entire program** but up to the part where I am having an error. When I run this in a command prompt I can recieve the first name fine, but after that the second cin.getline() does not read any input. Suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char name1[100], name2[100], name3[100];
    int numBat, numHit;
    double avg1, avg2, avg3;

    // Get Average for Player 1
    cout << "What's Your Name? ";
    cin.getline(name1, 100);

    cout << "How many times have you been at bat? ";
    cin >> numBat;

    if(numBat < 0 || numBat > 25)
    {
        cout << "ERROR ::: Number of Times at Bat Cannot Be Less Than 0 or Greater Than 25. Run Program Again." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {

        cout << "How many times have you hit the ball? ";
        cin >> numHit;

        if(numHit < 0)
        {
            cout << "ERROR ::: Number Hit Cannot Be Less Than 0. Run Program Again." << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            // Calculate Average for Player 1
            avg1 = numHit / numBat;

            // Get Average for Player 2
            cout << "What's Your Name? ";
            cin.getline(name2, 100);

            cout << "How many times have you been at bat? ";
            cin >> numBat;

            cout << "How many times have you hit the ball? ";
            cin >> numHit;
                  }
         }
}
```

Comment: Was about to tag this as homework... But there's already 5 tags. lol

Comment: :/ is it necessary to have a homework tag? I feel like that deters people from helping me with my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a buffer problem. Try to flush the `cin` before the second `getline`:

```
cin.clear(); // clear the buffer
cin.sync();
```

if that does not work, try something like this:

```
cin.ignore(256, '\n'); // ignore the endline and char(256)
```

Comment: A Winrar Is You! What's the difference between ignore and getline()?

Comment: `cin.clear()` doesn't clears the buffer but clears the error bits of `istream`

Answer (score 0):

After the `getline`, you need to output a newline using `cout << endl;`.

Comment: Why didn't I have to do that on my first cin.getline() ? It goes through without problem

Comment: You do need to do it after the first 'getline'. That's why you're having a problem. After the person enter their name, you're not outputting a newline, so whatever you write next goes on the same line.

Comment: What I'm saying is the top half of the program runs fine & as expected without the above solution. Why is that?

Comment: Actually Now the CIN doesn't work at all, it isnt reading any input.

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
   cin >> numBat;
```

It doesn't read the newline, so the next cin.getline() will read that and continue.

Use

```
cin >> numBat;
cin.ignore(80,'\n');
```

Comment: Actually Now the CIN doesn't work at all, it isnt reading any input and we have to use the getLine, not sure why?